# Is it possible to create AR-Based App on device without ARKit or ARCore?

Tags: react-native, augmented-reality, arkit, arcore

I'm going to work on a cross-platform mobile application that will identify objects on a planar by creating a label and pointed to the objects on the planar in any angle. I am not sure if this is possible without ARKit or ARCore.

I have to use React Native as the development system, and I have searched a lot of libraries, but most of them are based on ARKit or ARCore, in which older devices do not support.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Might be worth to have a look at artoolkit http://www.artoolkitx.org/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [OpenCV.js](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d5/d10/tutorial_js_root.html). It works in the browser so maybe it also works with cross-platform apps.

Start with some of their tutorials to get to know the library. After that you could try to port the [Planar tracking example](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/dc/d16/tutorial_akaze_tracking.html) from C++ to Javascript

OpenCV is a well-established computer vision library which allows (and often times requires you) to get to the core of CV algorithms.